# Send Power View Report via Subscriptions?

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, subscription, powerview

i was just wondering if it was possible to send Power View Reports using Subscriptions, same as it was Possible with SSRS Reports,
 Anybody have an Idea ?
 Possible or not ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no native functionality to create a subscription for Power View reports, probably because they are meant to be used interactively.  As a workaround, you could probably come up with your own solution by writing code (C#, VB) to open the Power View in Excel and export or save as a PDF and execute it on a schedule.